# open new page, load HTML, follow link within the same page as done here: http://government.ru/en/

Tags: jquery, ajax, lightbox, innerhtml, deep-linking

How to load external pages, follow links, load HTML within the same page as done on this website: http://government.ru/en/ ? Did they use a js or jquery plugin or Ajax or innerhtml to accomplish it? I'd like to know how to do it with that fade in/fade out effect and deep-linking.

Thank you in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/)  function to show external pages into your page.

you can use this type of method

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        $('div').load(url);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. But how to add the link to the URL? For example: i'm on the website http://example.com, i click on a link and it opens within the page itself and also the URL changes to e.g. http://example.com/link.html or something like that.